# Wordpress website starts downloading instead of loading the page in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, migration

I migrated my Wordpress website from one hosting to another. It was working perfectly on old hosting but on new hosting, it starts downloading every page that I try to access. I removed the .ht-access file and I started seeing blank pages. I set WP-Debug to true as well but nothing appears. Now, I don't know which line in .ht-access file is causing the issue. Here is the code of .ht-access

```
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Please tell me how this can be fixed. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

take a backup of your htaccess file and put only below code in the htaccess file

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you change the links in database because wordpress uses the parmanent links like http://example.com/string like this.

Comment: are you using cache on your site?

Comment: take a backup od your htaccess file and put only this code and retry

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Same blank screen after doing that. Tested on another browser and it showed HTTP 500 Error

Comment: ok then check the file permissions it should be 644 for files and 755 for folders.